How to depend java 21 compiled class on java 17 project (Gradle)
HelloWorld/
  ├── core
  └── api/
    ├── stable
    └── preview

HelloWorld project is java 17 project
We cant upgrade project java version due to our almost client..
api/preview project uses Java 21 external library
So, I did it
preview/build.gradle
java {
    toolchain.languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21) // due to java 21 external library
}

and
core/build.gradle
dependencies {
    compileOnly(":api:stable")
    compileOnly(":api:preview") // Its java 21 project
}
java {
    toolchain.languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17) //Its java 17 project
}

For example,

If client use WIn10, use WinUtil 3 (JDK 17)
If client use Win11 use WinUtil 4 (JDK 21)

So, I need it
What should I do?
I want to know how to use a Java 21 project in an older Java project using Gradle.

"Jar must be java 17 compiled things.. What should I do?" - Recompile the external library for Java 17.   And if you can't do that ... then you can't use it in your Java 17 project.

for example, If client use WIn10, use WinUtil 3 (JDK 17). If client use Win11 use WinUtil 4 (JDK 21). but project must be 17 project
I already did it a few years ago..
but I cant remember detail of it..
It is possible

Well a few years ago you either ran the code on Java 21 or you recompiled the external dependency for Java 17.  (Or maybe the versions were much much older and you found some tool for converting classfiles to an older classfile version; e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502433. But AFAIK you can't do that for Java 21.)

The fact is that a Java 17 JVM will not load a Java 21 classfile.  So you need to work with that constraint.

Maybe creating a multi-release JAR would help; see https://www.baeldung.com/java-multi-release-jar, https://blog.gradle.org/mrjars.

Java 21 class file and Java 17 class file in one jar without multi-release.
And Project jdk is 17, IDE project jdk = 21, IDE project language level = 17.
And I use java toolchain on Java 21 module.
hmm...

Well that Jar file containing a mix of Java 17 and 21 class files will fail if you run it on a Java 17 JVM and the app attempts to load any of the Java 21 class files.

correct. but I not just use java 21 in 17 enviroment.
My project is.. If client use Jdk21, use util code with java 21 code,
If client use >Jdk21, use util code with java 17 code.
and My project codes is java 17 code

You could potentially make your app do some clever dynamic class loading and isolate the Java 21 dependent code.  Sort of like what mrjar's do ... but by hand.  But why not simply use mrjars?  Why reinvent the wheel?

hmm.......
if I (JavaUtil.getVersion() < 21) Util.JDK17.findSmth();
else Util.JDK21.findSmth();

this work must be I can do in 1 minute as I remember as
Its not edit class file, and easy to do, gradle something

You need to be more careful than that.  You need a common API interface, and then dynamically load different implementations of that interface depending on the JVM version.  You have to avoid any dependencies on the Java 21 specific classes in any code that will be loaded in Java 17.  That statement statically depends on both Util.JDK17 and Util.JDK21 and will cause both classes to be partially loaded (I think).   Assuming that you run it on Java 17 you will get a classloading error.

I mean... Util21 in api:preview Util17 in api.stable
and api:preview project is jdk 21, api:stable jdk 17
but core project is jdk 17 and (JavaUtil.getVersion() < 21) Util17.findSmth() blabla

I think you get the same problem.  But you should try it out if you don't think so.   In fact, it would be much simpler if you >did< try it out and (if it doesn't work) showed us the code and the exception stacktrace so that we can understand and correct it.  (All this "smth" and "blabla" stuff could be ... anything.)
